# Mysql error: column count doesn't match at row

Tags: mysql

When i'm trying to insert multiple values, i get an error as

> column count doesn't match at row

I tried inserting each of the values separately and it works perfectly

```
insert into book.books(title, author_fname,author_lname,released_year,stock_quantity,pages)
values  ('The Namesake','Jhumpa','Lahiri',2003,32,291),
('Norse Mythology','Neil','Gaiman',2016,43,304),
('American Gods','Neil','Gaiman',2001,12,465),
('Interpreter of maladies','Jhumpa','Lahiri',1996,97,198),
('A hologram for the king: A novel','Dave','Eggers',2012,154,352),
('The Circle','Dave','Eggers',2013,26,504),
('Just kids','Patti','Smith',2010,55,304),
('The Amazing adventures of kavalier & lay','Micheal','Chabon',2000,68,634),
('A heartbreaking world of staggering genius','Dave','Eggers',2001,104,437),
('Coraline','Neil','Gaiman',2003,100,208),
('What we talk about when we talk about love:stories','Raymond','carver',1981,23,176),
('where i am calling from : selected stories','Raymond','carver',1989,12,526),
('white noise','Don','Delillo',1985,49,320),
('Cannery row','John','Steinbeck',1945,95,181),
('Oblivion:stories','David','Foster Wallace',2004,172,329),
('Consider the lobster''David','Foster Wallace',2005,92,343);
```

Where did I go wrong? How to insert them all at once without getting an error?

Comment: Typo last line, you've forgot a comma. `('Consider the lobster' COMMA MISSING THERE 'David','Foster Wallace',2005,92,343)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check **last record** 
('Consider the lobster''David','Foster Wallace',2005,92,343);

This would be...
('Consider the lobster','David','Foster Wallace',2005,92,343);